# React Call on mount (using hook) wants dependencies still in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Would like a chunk of code being called only once, something `componentDidMount` used to do everyone points to using [empty dependency](https://dev.to/trentyang/replace-lifecycle-with-hooks-in-react-3d4n) array:

```
useEffect( () => {
    // Code to be executed here
}, []);
```

So, I'm using a custom hook where:

```
const { token } = useParams();
const { methodToCall } = useCustomHook();

useEffect( () => {
    if (token) {
        methodToCall();
    }
}, []);
```

However, react lint complains that useEffect method has missing dependencies. Because `methodToCall` is a function that gets rendered every time, this use effect always gets called on render if I so include it as a dependency. Is there a better way to call `methodToCall()` only on first render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

useEffect is the way to go, now you can still ignore the warning but thats not good especially because in newer versions these dependencies might be inserted automatically by a transpiler.

However eslint will only complain if the token, methodToCall are indeed actual dependencies. It seems here from your code that they are indeed since you are getting these using custom hooks. If these are constant javascript variables then declare them not in the component body, but before it is defined, and the linter will not complain.

If these are indeed results of custom hooks you could do something like this

```
// you might choose a better name depending on your actual code
const [wasMyOneTimeEffectExecuted, setWasMyOneTimeEffectExecuted] = useState(false)

// and then in useEffect
useEffect( () => {
    if (token && wasMyOneTimeEffectExecuted === false) {
        setWasMyOneTimeEffectExecuted(true)
        methodToCall();
    }
}, [methodToCall, token, wasMyOneTimeEffectExecuted]);
```